# Which statistical test should I apply?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have 2 sets of data.

First set is historical data and samples are taken up to a date. It has 3000 samples.

Second set of new samples are taken after that particular date. It has 400 samples.

I want to compare these two sets of data statistically.

Which test should I apply? Student-T or Z test?
How can I do it in MATLAB?

Comment: What are you interested in finding out from this new data? If all you want to compare is means then a t-test should work if your data is normally distributed.

Comment: what type of t test I should use?

Answer (score 2):

You can perform Welch's $t$-test in MATLAB using the function [`ttest2`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/ttest2.html). Welch's $t$-test is a version of Student's $t$-test adapted to the case where variances and/or sample sizes may not be equal (both populations should still have a normal distribution, however!). See here:

[Wikipedia: Welch's $t$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch's_t-test)

Comment: IF samples are normally distributed.